# Insert an associative array into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database with a table I've just created with the following info-
**table**: rec_nutr
**columns:** 
nutrDesc varchar(60),
nutr_ttl float,
units    varchar(7),
I have a php array called $stuff that I want to insert into this table.  When I print_r($stuff) it looks like:

```
Array
(
[0]=> Array
  (
    [nut]=> Protein
    [amt]=> 0.85
    [units]=> g
   )
[1]=> Array
  (
    [nut]=> Energy
    [amt]=> 717
    [units]=> kcal
   )
etc.
)
```

The connection is a PDO object named $db and this is one of the many different variations I've unsuccessfully used to insert the array

```
foreach ($stuff as $row){
  $nut = $row['nut'];
  $amt = $row['amt'];
  $units = $row['units'];
  $query= "insert into rec_nutr (nutrDesc, nutr_ttl,units)values ($nut,$amt,$units)"; 

  $statement= $db->exec($query);

}
```

When I run this I don't receive any error messages, however the information is not inserted into the table.

I've also tried using this statement

```
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rec_nutr(nutrDesc, nutr_ttl,units) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)");
  foreach($stuff as $row) {
      $stmt->execute(array( $row['nut'],$row['amt'],$row['units']));
  }
```

but again no luck

Note: The array was pulled off a web page using JSON then decoded using JSON_decode.  I then used print_r($stuff) to check the array.  I tried using floatvar() on amt in case it was coming in as a string but that didn't seem to help.  Is there something I can add to see if there is an error message on insertion?

Comment: Try enclosing string values in quotes or using a prepared statement with parameter binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I had only given SELECT privileges to the user I was using to log on to the database with!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

String values need to be enclosed in quotations:

```
$query= "insert into rec_nutr (nutrDesc, nutr_ttl,units) values ('$nut',$amt,'$units')";
```

**Using PDO, you should look into [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and binding parameters. It will ensure your values are entered correctly and will do very well at protecting you from sql-injection.** The above code is vulnerable to SQL injection if `$stuff` is untrusted input.

Comment: I just tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.  Do I even put quotes around variables like that?

Comment: Only for string type values. Sorry, `nutr_ttl` is probably a numeric type, so no quotes around that one.